# Change language of iOS app in App Store

Tags: ios

In App Store my iOS app is declared as "Language En" but it should be "Language German". How can I do this? In iTunes Connect I set the language to German, but it doesn't work. What do I have to set in Xcode do make the app declared as german?

Comment: DId you translated your app in german language. The base language of an app is english.  You should set the primary language as german.

Answer (score 4):

Set `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` to `de_DE` in your project's xxx-Info.plist.

From Apple's docs:

> CFBundleDevelopmentRegion (String - iOS, OS X) specifies the default
>   language and region for the bundle, as a language ID. For example,
>   English for the United Kingdom has the language ID en-UK. The system
>   uses this value if it cannot locate a resource for the user’s
>   preferred language.

for more info follow [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-130430).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that from iTunesConnect. The language is read from your IPA and the default language for base language is english. I think that this is a pretty nasty issue and I've filed a radar to Apple asking for a language selection during the creation of a project.